# JQuery bug on simultaneous fadeIn / fadeOut over absolute positioned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, css-position

I have a collection of elements I want to show one after another, fading out the first while fading in the second simultaneously, and cycle them when reaching the last one

If I position absolutely the first element, while fading out, the second one doesn't have any problems positioning, EXCEPT if it is the last one. There is a bug (?) that makes the last item, that should be fading out, to use the space as if it has a relative position, after setting the position to absolute.

You can see the bug here: http://jsfiddle.net/XekVc/

This behavior is present in Chrome 12.0 (I think is last version) and FF 3.6.17

I don't want to make all of them absolutely positioned, since the container in my application has other relatively positioned elements which I would have to adjust after this, so it is my last alternative.

Does anyone have an idea if this is a bug on my code, or is this a jquery / browser's render engine issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing with the fiddle, I can avoid the bug by placing the leaving element before the coming one, by doing a `element.prependTo(element.parent())` before changing its positioning.

http://jsfiddle.net/e253r/

This can be a workaround, but I'm still genuinely interested in finding if it is a bug and where...

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** so I decided to check out the `.animate()` route:

```
.thing {
    background-color: #9E9E9E;
    border: 2px solid #393939;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
}

$(function() {
    var index = 0;
    $('.thing').css("opacity", "0");
    var current = $('.thing:first-child').show();
    $('.thing:last-child').css({
        "position": "static"
    });
    setInterval(function() {
        index = (index + 1) % 3;
        var next = $($('.thing')[index]);
        current.animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1500);
        next.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1500);

        current = next;
    }, 2000);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XekVc/16/

seems to work

Comment: the problem with that is that he has other content which will mess up when everything is absolute (which will happen at times in this case)... http://jsfiddle.net/XekVc/13/

Comment: It almost works, with a downside: the container element will have no height during the transition. Compare http://jsfiddle.net/XekVc/14/ to my workaround (in the solution I posted above) http://jsfiddle.net/e253r/1/ -- edit: ninja'd

Comment: Ah i see its the same problem with the absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this happens. Can you set top: 0 in addition to absolute positioning? The container position would have to be set too

http://jsfiddle.net/XekVc/17/